# How to create a new column (variable) out of the results in existing columns of a dataset

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column called "Standard" as a composite of the results from three tests (three different columns in my dataset).

- If all three tests are positive, the standard will be called "Strong".
- If two out three tests are positive, the standard will be called "Medium"
- If only one test is positive, the standard will be called "Scanty"
- And if none of the tests is positive, the standard will be called "Failed".

I have about 100 records in the dataset and I would like to find a way to do this in R without having to proceed manually. I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to try and I am new to R. Any help or hint will be really appreciated. Thanks.

The dataset looks like this:

```
     ID   Test_1   Test_2   Test_3
     1   positive positive positive
     2   positive negative positive
     3   positive positive negative
     4   negative negative positive
     5   negative positive negative
     6   negative negative negative
     7   positive negative negative
```

Below is what I am expecting the final dataset to look like:

```
     ID   Test_1   Test_2   Test_3   Standard
     1   positive positive positive   Strong
     2   positive negative positive   Medium
     3   positive positive negative   Medium
     4   negative negative positive   Scanty
     5   negative positive negative   Scanty
     6   negative negative negative   Failed
     7   positive negative negative   Scanty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `rowSums` to index the vector of Standard values (note that they have to be in the correct order)

```
idx <- rowSums(df[-1] == "positive") +1L
df$Standard <- c("Failed", "Scanty", "Medium", "Strong")[idx]
```

Result:

```
> df
  ID   Test_1   Test_2   Test_3 Standard
1  1 positive positive positive   Strong
2  2 positive negative positive   Medium
3  3 positive positive negative   Medium
4  4 negative negative positive   Scanty
5  5 negative positive negative   Scanty
6  6 negative negative negative   Failed
7  7 positive negative negative   Scanty
```

Comment: Docendos, Thanks you for providing me with a solution to my problem. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` is one way to do it

```
df$new <- apply(df[,-1], 1, function(i) length(i[i == 'positive']))
df$standard <- ifelse(df$new == 3, 'Strong', ifelse(df$new == 2, 'Medium', ifelse(df$new == 1, 'Scanty', 'Failed')))
df
#      ID   Test_1   Test_2   Test_3 new standard
#    1  1 positive positive positive   3   Strong
#    2  2 positive negative positive   2   Medium
#    3  3 positive positive negative   2   Medium
#    4  4 negative negative positive   1   Scanty
#    5  5 negative positive negative   1   Scanty
#    6  6 negative negative negative   0   Failed
#    7  7 positive negative negative   1   Scanty
```